# Have a class be a NO-OP for any flavor other then a specific flavor

Tags: android, gradle

What i want :
I want to have some class say Example, which used in the main project, be a complete NO-OP when being built with any <build type><flavor> other then <build type>example, only when built with <build type>example flavors, it should have code that really does stuff.

What i tried:

I added an Example flavor to gradle:

```
    flavorDimensions "example"
    productFlavors {
        create("example") {
            dimension = "example"
        }
    }
```

Added source to the coresponding source set:

src->example->com.example->Example.java

Now i am stuck with how to add a NO-OP Example.java so that it will be used for any OTHER flavor.
tried to add to

src->main->com.example->Example.java

But its considered redeclaration (since main is shared between all flavors). So how can it be done?

NOTE: the user of Example class should not care or be aware of weither Example class methods are complete NO-OPs or not, I want him to be able to have same minimal (without annoying if checks) source code be built succesfully with NO-OPs methods in <build type>example builds, and with real code in <build type><any flavor other then example> builds.

Answer (score 0):

Step #0: Remove the no-op class from the `main` sourceset, if you still have it there

Step #1: Add another flavor

Step #2: Add your no-op class to the flavor added in Step #1

Step #3: Repeat steps #1 and #2 for any other flavors that you need

Comment: What if thats a library that should be used by costumers? they can add flavours as they like but need to add that no op class manually? is there a way around it?

Comment: @OfekRon: None that I can think of.